# Finding the maximum of step response for a given transfer funtion

Tags: calculus, optimization, laplace-transform, control-theory

Assuming that the following transfer function is given:

$$F(s)=\frac{\Sigma_{k=0}^m b_k s^k}{\Sigma_{k=0}^n a_k s^k}$$

$$m\le n$$

Lets say $g(t)$ is the step response to this transfer function.

How to find the $\max(|g(t)|)$ without solving numerical ODE equation (a numerical time domain simulation)?

Comment: is the transfer function stable?

Comment: @null, Yes it is absolutely stable.

Comment: You can calculate the inverse Laplace transform to obtain $g(t)$ and calculate $t_0$ values such that $g'(t_0) = 0$. If the system is exponentially stable, then $g(t_0)$ should give the maximum (minimum) value for the the smallest $t_0$.